# How to edit an array from another class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, static

I have created a 2d array (used as a playing board) and in another class I want to take my array and be able to perform operations on it.

My array definition (in class `PlayingBoard`):

```
public char[][] myGrid = new char[12][12];
```

Now I want to manipulate this array from other classes in my project. I tried to call this grid in the class it was **not** defined in

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        PlayingBoard.myGrid[i][j] = 'x';
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Non-static variable `myGrid` cannot be referenced from static context

How can I reference, edit, and operate on `myGrid` from this second class?

Comment: Seem to have a minor mixup in the declaration - is this supposed to be an `int` array or a `char` array? It looks like it should be `char`

Comment: @JonK `char` array, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must change one of the two things:

1. declare `myGrid` as static

   ```
   public static char[][] myGrid = new char[8][8];
   ```
2. access `myGrid` via an object instance:

   ```
   PlayingBoard pb = new PlayingBoard();
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
           pb.myGrid[i][j] = 'x';
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The answers point to the use of a static array and this makes me feel sad from an OO point of view.

How about ensuring your playing board has a properly encapsulated structure, with an "addPiece" method?

```
PlayingBoard myBoard = new PlayingBoard();

int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        myBoard.addPiece(i,j, 'x');
    }
}
```

Even then, if your pieces themselves are "smart", you'll want to create an object that wraps them rather than just storing a char.

```
public PlayingPiece[][] _board = new PlayingPiece[8][8];
```

Also, you're using 12 in the loop but 8 in the initialisation, so expect an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I was only updating the question though.. I wanted it to be useful for whoever else got this problem rather than the mess it was!